# Angular 5 Unit test Router Navigation

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, testing, jasmine

I want to test this function. When return true I want to navigate in this router.

My component code:

```
  onLogin() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.auth.login(
      this.loginForm.controls['username'].value,
      this.loginForm.controls['password'].value)
      .subscribe(
      result => {
        if (result === true) {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        } else {
          this.loading = false;
        }
      }
      );
  }
```

I tried this test, that result is true

```
  it('should call service.login when onLogin', done => {
    const mock = [];
    spyOn(component['auth'], 'login').and.callThrough()
    component['auth'].login('abcs', '1').subscribe(
      result => {
        if (result === true) {
        }
        console.log(result)
          done();
      });
    component.onLogin();
  })
```

Comment: Your test doesn't make sense. You're subscribing to a method that isn't on the component under test, and which you've mocked out then called back through to. What are you actually trying to test here? You should properly mock out the auth to return an observable of `true` then test that `navigate` on a mocked router gets called.

Comment: When the result is true, I want to navigate in `this.router.navigate(['/home']);` like in function.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but that's not at all the behaviour the test is driving out. You're calling a spied method on a collaborator of the component under test, which makes no sense at all. I'd advise reading e.g. https://angular.io/guide/testing and thinking more carefully about what's in and out of scope for the tests of the component.